# Binding two dependency properties from two different usercontrols

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have created two separate usercontrols, they are meant to work together.

The first one is a simple usercontrol with a thumb attached to it, the thumb makes the control move around by dragging, this is simple and working.

XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Width="15" Height="15" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"/>
</Canvas>
```

Code-Behind: A dependency property called **Position**, when Setter is called it updates the usercontrol's margin.

```
public partial class ThumbPoint : UserControl
{
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); this.Margin = new Thickness(value.X, value.Y, 0, 0); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Position.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(ThumbPoint), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));

    public ThumbPoint()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Position = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Position = new Point(Position.X + e.HorizontalChange, Position.Y + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

The second UserControl is called StraightLine, its composed of a Line control

XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line x:Name="Line" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

Code-Behind: A dependency property called **StartPosition**, when Setter is called it updates the Line X1 and Y1 (starting position of the line).

```
public partial class StraightLine : UserControl
{
    public Point StartPosition
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(StartPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartPositionProperty, value); Line.X1 = value.X; Line.Y1 = value.Y; }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartPosition.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartPosition", typeof(Point), typeof(StraightLine), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));

    public StraightLine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Line.X1 = 0;
        Line.Y1 = 0;

        Line.X2 = 300;
        Line.Y2 = 200;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to bind them together on the mainwindow.xaml:

```
<Canvas>
    <local:ThumbPoint x:Name="ThumbPoint"/>
    <local:StraightLine StartPosition="{Binding Position, ElementName=ThumbPoint}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Desired effect: DependencyProperty StartPosition of the StraightLine should be updated.

Whats happening: It's not being updated so only the ThumbPoint is moving.

Answer (score 0):

binding doesn't use common property wrappers for DP (`public Point StartPosition`), it uses `SetValue()` directly, so code in setter isn't invoked.

What is needed is propertyChangedCallback:

```
public Point StartPosition
{
    get { return (Point)GetValue(StartPositionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StartPositionProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StartPositionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("StartPosition", typeof(Point), typeof(StraightLine), new PropertyMetadata(new Point(), OnStartPositionChanged));

private static void OnStartPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
   StraightLine c = (StraightLine) d;
   c.Line.X1 = c.StartPosition.X; 
   c.Line.Y1 = c.StartPosition.Y; 
}
```

in ThumbPoint `public Point Position` property has the same issue but it works there because you use setter directly: `Position = new Point()`

Alternatively bind X1 and Y1 value in xaml:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line x:Name="Line" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"
          X1="{Binding StartPosition.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StraightLine}}"
          Y1="{Binding StartPosition.Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StraightLine}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

(or use ElementName instead of RelativeSource)